# react & apollo: element not returning

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, apollo

For some reason, when using:

```
export const allBilderLinkses = gql`
query bild($name: String!){
  allBilderLinkses(filter: {collectionName: {collectionName: $name}}) {
    bildLink
  }
}
`

const Images = ({ data: { loading, error, allBilderLinkses } }) => {
  if (error) return <h1>Error fetching the post!</h1>;
  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div>

        {allBilderLinkses.map(bild => (
          <ImageContainer bg={bild.bildLink}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <h2>Loading post...</h2>;
};


class ExpandedCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Container>
        <h1>test</h1>
      </Container>
      <Images />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(allBilderLinkses, {
  options:({match}) => ({ variables: {
     name: match.params.id
   },
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
}),
}) (Images, ExpandedCard);
```

Only `<Images />` is being rendered. `<h1>test</h1>` does not get rendered, in fact via chrome dev tools, the h1-tag is not even an element. 
Normally in my builds, a gql query doesnt interfere with the rest of the component. The only differences I can see in this piece of code, are the added variable in the gql query and the variable options in the export statement of graphql.
It seems for no reason, not to load the h1-tag, why does it do that? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the render function for Container tag? Looks like it might not have the this.props.children in its render?

Comment: the Container tag is simply a styled.div, no render function present...

Comment: Ahh i found your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the second parameter in the graphql HoC call.

It should be `graphql(...)(ExpandedCard)`

graphql is a HoC (higher order component). It can be thought of as a component that takes a component as input and returns an enhanced component. HoC's are used to share cross cutting concerns across components.

So graphql would look like as follows

```
const graphql = (wrappedComponent, someData) => () => <WrappedComponent {...graphql props based on someData} />
```

The wrapped component is the component you want to enhance with graphql functionality.